# Combine all values of a stream into an array and serve it as a value of other stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bacon.js

I have a database query, that returns an array, I convert it to EventStream like so:

```
var stream = Bacon.fromNodeCallback(queryManager, "findAll").flatMap(Bacon.fromArray);
```

And then with each value of the stream, I need to update its properties:

```
var otherStream = stream.map(function(val) {
  val.property1 = "blah blah";
  return val;
});
```

So now I want to get all values of "otherStream" as array, then I can manipulate them at once. Is it possible to do this with Bacon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just map the results array without converting it to separate stream values.

```
Bacon.fromNodeCallback(queryManager, "findAll").map(function(results) {
  return results.map(function(val) {
    val.property1 = "blah blah";
    return val;
  });
}));
```